# How to find files in a directory with same name but different extensions? Also restrict some extensions?

Tags: linux, bash

I try to find files in a directory that have mp4 mkv extensions only. But I also want that these finded files same name, but different extensions. For example: `video.mp4 video.mkv` . I tried to restrict extensions that I wanted like below, but I couldn't do the rest:

```
for i in *
    do
        case "${i##*.}" in
            [mM][kK][vV])
            FFmpegForCompressAutomaticJob
            ;;
            [mM][pP]4)
            FFmpegForCompressAutomaticJob
            ;;
            *)
            continue
            ;;
        esac
    done
```

Comment: Find in what? what is your OS? are you trying to write a code or direct shell commands?

Comment: I use Linux Mint. I try to write a shell script with ```sh```, no ```bash```.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? What is `FFmpegForCompressAutomaticJob` ? You don't seem to be passing `"$i"` as an argument... Do you want to run that for every `.mp4`, `.mP4`, `.Mkv`, etc. Or only run it for a file if it's corresponding `.???` doesn't already exist? – Are you trying to make your script portable or could you use bash/etc. –specific features?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function instead ( or a script if you like ).

```
processor() {
  for f; do
    [ -f "$f" ] || continue
    case $f in
      *.[mM][kK][vV])
        echo "converting $f"
        : Do something here ;;
      *.[mM][pP]4)
        echo "converting $f"
        : Do another thing here ;;
      *.???)
        echo "Found $f" ;;
    esac
  done
}
```

Now try it in a directory

```
processor *
```